# How to scroll to the new position of an element using the scrollTo plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollto

I wrote a jQuery click event handler that hides all elements except one and used scrollTo to scroll the window to the top of that element like this:

```
$(".jumbotron").click(function(){
            $('.jumbotron').not(this).toggle("slow");
            $.scrollTo($(this).position().top, 500);    
        });
```

But the window scrolls to the element's old position while it has already moved to another position. How do I hide all other elements and scroll to a new position?

Answer (score 0):

Better to do this in the callback:

```
$(".jumbotron").click(function(){
   var $this = $(this); // cache it here
   $('.jumbotron').not(this).toggle("slow", function(){
      $.scrollTo($this.position().top, 500);
   });
});
```

[.toggle( [duration ] [, complete ] )](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-duration-complete)

Answer (score 0):

As an improvement on what Jai proposed:

```
$(".jumbotron").click(function(){
   var that = this;
   $('.jumbotron').not(that).toggle("slow", function(){
      $.scrollTo(that, 500);
   });
});
```

That should work, scrollTo accepts DOMNodes and jQuery objects as well.